# OnActivityResult not triggered inside Fragment

Tags: android-camera, android-fragmentactivity, android-support-library, android-camera-intent, onactivityresult

I'm calling ACTION IMAGE CAPTURE intent from a fragment, and I've implemented the `onActivityResult()` in same fragment but the onActivityResult is not triggered while running it with my note2 device. Check the code snippets below that I used.

It worked fine when I am not using

```
 import android.support.v4
```

---

- Activity which I open fragment

  ```
        public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity {
  ```
- Fragment which I call Camera Intent

  ```
       public class SaveCardFragment extends Fragment { 
       private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1888;
       ...
  ```
- Calling Camera Intent

  ```
       Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
       startActivityForResult(intent,CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
       ...
  ```
- Function to detect activity result

  ```
      @Override 
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
      Log.d("Result", ""+requestCode);
      }
  ```
- Configuration in AndroidManifest

  ```
       <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
       <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
       <application
       android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
       android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
       >
       <activity android:name=".HomeActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_home"/>
  ```

Comment: `getActivity().startActivityForResult(SaveCardFragment.this,intent,CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);` Does this compile? I don't see a version of `startActivityForResult()` which takes a `Fragment` as its first parameter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment .

Comment: call startActivityForResult(), not getActivity().startActivityForResult()

Comment: startActivityForResult(intent,CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);//this is the  function call I'm using

Comment: i see you are using getActivity().startActivityForResult

Comment: now that is replaced with startActivityForResult, but still onActivityResult is not triggered

Comment: did you override HomeActivity.onActivityResult?

Comment: no i did not. is it required?

Comment: hmmm,  its strange,  it should work then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60331/discussion-between-hara-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm calling ACTION IMAGE CAPTURE intent from a fragment (...)

That's not quite true. Look at the following line of code:

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(SaveCardFragment.this,intent,CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Key to notice is that you call `startActivityForResult()` on the hosting activity (`HomeActivity`), not the fragment (`SaveCardFragment`), hence the result is delivered to the activity and not propagated any further. If you want the result to be delivered to the fragment, ensure you call `startActivityForResult()` on the **fragment**. In other words, just get rid of the `getActivity()` prefix:

```
startActivityForResult(SaveCardFragment.this,intent,CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

See: [Fragment#startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

Comment: I've made corrections to my code but still onActivityResult is not triggered

Comment: @hara: Are you instantiating and adding the `SaveCardFragment` dynamically (in code) or is it statically declared in a layout? If the former applies, make sure you're not accidentally re-adding/replacing the originally calling fragment. Perhaps you could add some more code that shows how you "open" your fragment?

Comment: @hara: another thought: the parameters of your `startActivityForResult()` call don't seem right. What's that first parameter (`SaveCardFragment.this`) doing there? All you should need is the intent and a request code. You didn't declare your own `startActivityForResult()` method by any chance, did you?

Comment: I've corrected the code I'm using just an intent and request code in that function. My Fragment is statically declared one, and I did not declare startActivityForResult() method. What else I can add while starting the fragment?

Comment: fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager
.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, tag);
transaction.addToBackStack(tag).commit();//this code I use to add //fragment

Comment: @hara: sounds like you have two fragment instances on top of each other. If your fragment is statically declared, don't add another one using a transaction. Do one, not both. Besides, you can't replace a statically declared fragment. The fact that you 'solved' it using an activity suggests that the fragments are probably not set up correctly.